# Is it possible to trace a delegation method call, if non existent?

Tags: objective-c

It is hard to put into one subject line, I guess...
What I want to accomplish is figure out, if a delegation method call was placed and reveal its name.

Say we have a specific class A. Class A is using a delegate.

```
classA* a=[[classA alloc] init];
a.delegate = self;
[a doThingA];
```

Now, `doThingA` is calling an undocumented function upon completion for example - `didThingA`
How is it possible, now, to actually monitor `didThingA` function call when it's fired?

Another example, if we did not have ViewController's documentation, is there a way to trace the function calls of viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear etc?

Comment: If the delegate method is not implemented, it is not called and you can't trace it. You could override `respondsToSelector:` and see what comes along.

Comment: If the delegate has to conform to a protocol you can see the header.